# How to take the value of JavaScript variable using .Net framework or C# programming language?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I have code shown below, i want to get value of title and videoid. Title and vidioid is elements of session and session is element of units. I am getting confuse to get their value using c# or .Net framework.

Can i take their values? if i could take their values, how to do it?

```js
<script>
  
var MainData = {
            config: {
                debug: false
            },
            server: {
                "deviceDownloadCardData": [],
                "pageData": {
                    "legacyRendered": false,
                     "unitsData": {
                        "isTeacher": false,
                        "isAdmin": false,
                        "units": [
                            {
                                "id": 468400,
                                "sessions": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 2472822,
                                        "title": "Introduction",
                                        "videoId": "bc:123456789",
                                        "playerID": 3890928181001,
                                    }
                                ] 
                             }
                        ],
                    },
                    "videoPlayerData": {
                        "totalSessionsDuration": "14m",
                        "units": [
                            {
                                "id": 468400,
                                "sessions": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 2472822,
                                        "title": "Introduction",
                                        "videoId": "bc:123456789",
                                        "playerID": 3890928181001, 
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
};
  
</script>
```

Comment: I suggest you give more details when you ask something here. My answer below was based on assumptions, this is not good at all, but I tried to help. You should tell what specifically are you running with C#. Is it an WebApplication? WCF? What is it? And some background also helps. Why are you trying to do this? you want to store session data in some database? Do some validation with your C# app?

Comment: It's dekstop application. i am learning web scraping for my website.

Comment: and my website contains that Js for saving it's data. and i want to get that data for my dekstop application

Comment: So you should make your website application store this data in some store, like a database. Then there are many ways of getting this data in your desktop app. You could connect directly to this same database using your desktop, or you could use Web API and get the same data with http requests (using web api client), and there are other ways. To get things simpler for you, I suggest you try to save this data in a database firstly, then use your desktop app to connect to this same database and get it.

Comment: it means, i could not get data from script above if i i saved the data using Js.

Comment: It depends on where do you save the data. If you save in a database, then  sure you can get it from C#, by connecting to that database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to get data from javascript (client side) in C# (maybe server side).

I guess you're using WebApplication with MVC, if it's the case, then it runs in server side. To send this data from client to server, you could do by making an http post call. In ASP.NET WebApplication, you could implement some WebAPI to receive this request.

You should learn about [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) and about http requests.

Assuming you're using jQuery in client side, you would make a call like this to send data:

```
var session = MainData.server.pageData.unitsData.units[0].sessions[0];

console.log(session);

$.post("api/sessions",
    {
        "session": session
    }
).done(function () {
    alert("Call was successful");
}).fail(function () {
    alert("Something went wrong!");
});
```

Then you would write some WebAPI like this:

```
// A class to represent your session in C#
public class SessionModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string videoId { get; set; }
    public int playerId { get; set; }
}

// An ApiController for Sessions, with a post method...
public class SessionsApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult PostSession(SessionModel model)
    {
        // Use your session model here
        return Ok(); // Return an Ok action result
    }
}
```